# angular code not working after minification

Tags: angularjs, typescript

below code is not working with minification which seems obvious (the controller dependency will not be not working after minification) . Can some one please suggest the ideal way to write below code which will work with minification as well . just for your information , I am using typescript and I am not thinking to create new class or function for controller as it is very small so I would prefer to write inline block . thanks in advance ..

```
public openSpinModal(): void {
            if (!this.spinModalInstance) {
                this.marsAction.closeModal();
                this.isNeedToClsoe = false;
                this.spinModalInstance = this.$modal.open({
                    animation: true,
                    templateUrl: 'module/common/components/mars-modal/spinModalContent.html',
                    size: 'sm',
                    windowClass: "modal-vertical-centered",
                    controller: ($scope, $modalInstance) => {
                        this.marsAction.closeModal = () => {
                            $modalInstance.close();
                            this.isNeedToClsoe = true;
                        };
                    }
                });

                //removed code to keep question cleraner
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**below code worked for me -**

```
public openSpinModal(): void {
                if (!this.spinModalInstance) {
                    this.marsAction.closeModal();
                    this.isNeedToClsoe = false;
                    this.spinModalInstance = this.$modal.open({
                        animation: true,
                        templateUrl: 'module/common/components/mars-modal/spinModalContent.html',
                        size: 'sm',
                        windowClass: "modal-vertical-centered",
                        controller: ["$scope", "$modalInstance" , ($scope, $modalInstance) => {
                            this.marsAction.closeModal = () => {
                                $modalInstance.close();
                                this.isNeedToClsoe = true;
                            };
                        }
                    }]);

                    //removed code to keep question cleraner
                }
            }
```